# How to update TabLayout after adding a new Fragment to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have an activity that uses a ViewPager for multiple Fragments, the fragments controlled by a JSONArray object. When I add a new array and update the adapter, everything updates to the correct information except the TabLayout does not reflect the change until a scroll action takes place.

If I add a Fragment when I am on the current last fragment, a new frag is created and the model updates, but the TabLayout shows the current selected as the last tab. If you do a scroll motion, you can then see the new tab, but the view update is not automatic.

Has anyone run into this and do you have any ideas how to make the TabLayout view update?

Here is the Activity and Adapter:

@EActivity(R.layout.activity_displays)
public class DisplaysActivity extends FitActivity {

```
@ViewById(R.id.button_right)
FitButton rightButton;
@ViewById(R.id.displays_tabview)
TabLayout tabView;
ViewPager viewPager;
JSONArray huds;
DisplaysPagerAdapter mAdapter;


@AfterViews
public void AfterViews() {
    huds = StandardHuds.getStandardHudPagerData();
    mAdapter = new DisplaysPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.displays_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
    tabView.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabView.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Click(R.id.button_right)
void newHud() {
    addHud();
}


public class DisplaysPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public DisplaysPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return LegendFragment_.builder().build();
        } else {
            JSONArray a = new JSONArray();
            DisplayFragment frag = DisplayFragment_.builder().build();
            try {
                a = huds.getJSONArray(position - 1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frag.setHudArray(a);
            return frag;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return huds.length() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Legend";
        } else {
            return "Display " + position;
        }
    }
}

public void addHud() {
    JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray rowArray = new JSONArray();
    newArray.put(rowArray);
    newArray.put(rowArray);
    newArray.put(rowArray);
    huds.put(newArray);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.refreshDrawableState();
    tabView.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

}

xml of the ViewPager/TabLayout within the activity

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/displays_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/displays_tabview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="?attr/colorFitBg1"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorFitPrimary"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorFitPrimary" />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I have tried to update the tabView a few different ways, but the tab is still off of the screen. Changing the max offscreen count does not affect this problem.

Let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you in advance.